# Elliptic equation with Neumann boundary condition: RHS in $L^2$ implies solution in $L^\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

Consider the homogeneous Neumann problem $$-\Delta u + ku = f$$ $$\partial_\nu u = 0$$
 on a smooth, bounded domain $\Omega$.

If $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, do we obtain the regularity $u \in L^\infty(\Omega)$? Any reference would be appreciated.

I have seen a result giving Holder continuity of the solution if $f \in L^p$ for some $p$ which depends on the dimension but it has to be larger than 2. So this is overkill.

Comment: No. If your dimension is 4 or higher, just take any function $u$ in $W^{2,2}(\Omega)\setminus L^\infty$ that verifies the Neumann condition and $f$ the corresponding right hand side. For a concrete example when dimension is 5 or higher you can take any function $u$ such that near some point $x_0\in \Omega$ it looks like $\ln |x - x_0|$ and smooth elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks @WillieWong